# Запятая перед "и почему"

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед "и почему" в предложении:

Расскажи, что тебе нравится в ней и почему ты выбрал ее в жены.

Answer (score 1):

**Расскажи** (что?), ***что тебе нравится в ней и почему ты выбрал ее в жены.***

Запятая не ставится. Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с двумя однородными **изъяснительными** придаточными, соединенными одиночным союзом И.

Союзные слова в однородных изъяснительных придаточных могут быть разными (***что, почему***).

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая  не нужна.

Но тут есть интересный момент.
Возможны два варианта пунктуационного оформления фразы.

***Расскажи, что тебе нравится в ней и почему ты выбрал ее в жены.*** 
и
***Расскажи, что тебе нравится в ней и почему ты выбрал ее в жены?***

Запятая не нужна при использовании ни одного из них. Но объяснение разное. 
В первом случае это два соподчиненных придаточных, запятой они не разделяются.

Во втором придаточного нет вообще, "расскажи" выступает в роли вставной конструкции. Но тогда мы имеем два вопросительных предложения, которые соединены союзом И. На этот счет есть отдельное правило с тем же смыслом: запятая не нужна.

Важно понимать, что объяснение первого варианта не годится для второго - и наоборот.